# Install package from CTAN which is not available in TeX Live

Tags: packages, texlive, ctan, tlmgr, texdef

The [texdef](https://ctan.org/pkg/texdef?lang=en) package was recently updated to fix a [critical bug](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/texdef/issues/2/unescaped-left-brace-in-regex). The package is updated on CTAN, but because TeX Live is in its "freeze" period, attempting to update the package via `tlmgr update` does not work. I do not consider it an acceptable solution to wait until the freeze period is over. How can I install the most recent version?

Comment: Download the source and install it by hand.  It's only a single file (`texdef.pl`).

Comment: Also this bug is hardly critical.  It neither poses a security risk, nor does it make the application unusable.  It merely displays a warning.

Comment: Nevertheless, a good question. It is always possible to install to texmf-local, if you have the code. However, there is a problem: If you forget to remove the local code later, then it will continue to over-ride updated distribution code.

Comment: @HenriMenke Wrong, in Perl 5.26 the warning has been turned into a hard error that makes texdef completely inoperable.

Comment: Install texlive 2018 pretest. You can do it in parallel to your existing tex.

Comment: You can also patch your existing file and the patch will no longer get zapped by updates to your installation as there are no more updates to install ever. There's a patch around somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CAVEAT:** This answer holds only for packages which are available in the TDS format.  This is indicated by their filename on CTAN.  If the filename reads `<package>.tds.zip`, it is in TDS format.

---

You can simply install it by hand.  The `texdef` package is available in TDS format which makes the installation ridiculously easy.

1. Download [`texdef.tds.zip`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/support/texdef.tds.zip)
2. Unpack (probably you need `sudo` with it)

   ```bash
   unzip -o texdef.tds.zip -d `kpsexpand '$TEXMFDIST'`
   ```
3. [???](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/profit)
4. Profit

   ```
   $ texdef --version
   texdef: Version 1.8a -- 2018/03/28
   ```

---

For other packages extra steps might be necessary.  If the package contains files which have to be located via kpathsea, you have to rebuild the filename database.  Fonts have to be enabled in the map file.  For example with STIX2.

1. Download [`stix2-type1.tds.zip`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/fonts/stix2-type1.tds.zip).
2. Unpack (probably you need `sudo` with it)

   ```bash
   unzip -o stix2-type1.tds.zip -d `kpsexpand '$TEXMFDIST'`
   ```
3. Rebuild the filename database (probably you need `sudo` with it)

   ```bash
   mktexlsr
   ```
4. For fonts, enable the font in the map file (probably you need `sudo` with it)

   ```bash
   updmap-sys --enable Map stix2.map
   ```
5. [???](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/profit)
6. Profit

Comment: How can I uninstall the package, once I have installed it?

Comment: @RadonRosborough You can simply remove it using `tlmgr remove texdoc`.  I presume that you mean downgrading to the repository version which is achieved using `tlmgr install --reinstall texdoc`.

Comment: You should never install packages manually into TEXMFDIST. You should use TEXMFLOCAL. Moreover, this is not the recommended way to install map file fragments now.

Comment: @cfr (1) Of course you should install packages from CTAN in TEXMFDIST.  Otherwise they could never be overwritten by updates, once the package arrives in the official distribution.  You are probably thinking about packages which are *not* on CTAN.  (2) I am not aware of any other way to install fonts.

Comment: Hi. I came here from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427993/how-to-install-the-new-stix2-package?noredirect=1#comment1071007_427993. Thanks for the instructions. I followed them and install the package without any errors. However, when using it, I got `mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for ts1-stix2text-italic. mktexpk: perhaps ts1-stix2text-italic is missing from the map file.` Maybe the package source has a bug?

Comment: I added `\pdfmapfile{=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/stix2/stix2.map}` before `\usepackage{stix2}` and it works.

Comment: @Khue That means you did not run `updmap-sys` or it failed.

Comment: Thanks. I will check again tomorrow (I’m on my bed now :D). Oh I forgot to upvote, sorry...

Comment: @HenriMenke Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I take it you mean packages from TeX Live, rather than from CTAN. But this is not from TeX Live. It is manually installed. Generally, map file fragments are best added to `TEXMFLOCAL/web2c/updmap.cfg`. However, if you insist on installing to `TEXMFDIST`, then obviously you want them to end up in the `updmap.cfg` in `TEXMFSYSCONFIG`, so this point doesn't apply.