# How to install the new stix2 package?

Tags: fonts, stix

The stix2 package has been released recently:
https://ctan.org/pkg/stix2-type1?lang=en

In the documentation it is said that to be able to use it, one just needs to add `\usepackage{stix2}`. However, there is no `stix2.sty` included (there are only *.dtx, *.map,...).

How can I install this package from the provided files?

I was able to use the STIX Two font in XeLaTex, but I would like to see how it looks like in pdfLaTeX (I don’t like the ugly math symbols of the `unicode-math` package in XeLaTeX).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your best option is to install TeX Live 2018 pretest or wait two months until it is released.

Comment: @HenriMenke Does that cover font packages? The considerations here are very different, after all.

Comment: @cfr Of course you need to run `mktexlsr` and `updmap-sys --enable Map stix2.map` but that is the case for any manually installed font.

Comment: @cfr I have updated my answer to the other question, so that this one can be closed as a duplicate.